# Prevent Windows 11 from informing that an app is using a microphone

Tags: windows-11, notification-area

Whenever any app is using my microphone, Windows 11 alerts me about this by showing this icon in the tray bar:

[image]

Is there any way to turn this alert / feature off (as I find it annoying)?

Right-clicking the microphone icon gives you access to microphone configuration only and nothing about displaying a warning. There's also nothing about this in the taskbar settings:

[image]

Is there any other option to get rid of this?

Comment: Can you simply click-drag it into the "up arrow" next to it? I know most app notifications can be hidden that way, or could in Win 10, but not sure about system warnings like this.

Comment: When the icon is showing check if it can be hidden in "Other System Tray Icons" in the "Personalization/Taskbar"

Comment: @Mokubai I don't believe you can drag-n-drop system icon. At least this one at least on my computer cannot be dragged or moved anywhere.

Comment: @BlindSpots There's no "Other System Tray Icons" section in Windows 11 (it was in Windows 10 AFAIK). I only have "Taskbar corner icons" and "Taskbar corners overflow" groups in Personalisation > Taskbar. None of these two includes "Microphone" icon.

Comment: I'm running 11 but it might be a slightly different build.

Answer (score -2):

It is not currently possible to hide that icon in (at least several builds of) Windows 11.

A "workaround" is to uninstall Windows 11 and install a different OS.